# How do i do geocoding in a loop without getting the OVER QUERY LIMIT

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

Hi I have a program wherein I need to perform indefinite number of geocodings (usually between 20-200) and store the address in an array, however when I am doing geocoding in a loop I get Over query limit error. How do i get around this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI I tried doing it on my friend's website and it worked .... I guess googles per second limit is good enough to handle loops ...... i think i was out of my 2500 queries per day limit

Answer (score 1):

No one here is likely to give you a strategy to overcome this limitation.  The correct answer is that you need to cache these locally.  If that means you have 200 items then it may take you a day or two to generate the cache, but you need to re-implement your program in a way that it only requests a geocode from Google in the event that it is not already cached locally.

Comment: I can have request from any point on the map caching all the coordinates on the globe is not feasible and thats why I ask for a solution

Comment: @Nick - Then you're probably not going to achieve what you're after.  Google's policy restricts the number of lookups in a given time period.  This is clearly explained in their documentation here:  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/ and also referred to in the TOS for the Maps API.  You can sign up for a premium account to increase the limits, but there will be limits.

Comment: I know that there is a limit of 2500 Query per day but that is okay with me I just need to prove that the thing works, the only problem I have is geocoding in loop 100 times and making sure that I get all the 100 values int the array

Comment: @Nick - "Additionally, we enforce a request rate limit to prevent abuse of the service." You could try adding calls to Sleep() to slow your program down, but if you're attempting to fire off 100 requests in a loop nearly instantly you're abusing the service according to their definition of abuse.  The request rate limit is not specified directly, so 5 - 10 seconds between requests may be sufficient, but you'd need to test that or contact someone via a support channel to find out for certain how rapid is too rapid.